# Вызов функции js из python

Tags: javascript, python

Привет. Мне необходимо получить список логинов с сайта, но полный список высвечивается после нажатия на ссылку с событием **onclick**, которое вызывает функцию [js](/questions/tagged/js). Как через [python](/questions/tagged/python) вызвать эту функцию (**без selenium**, мне не это нужно).

[image: Надо нажимать на кнопочку "Все"]

**Действия:**

- Из файла `clear.txt` берутся ссылки
- Берётся `html` этой страницы
- Вызывается функция, которая показывает все логины
- Логины парсятся
- Скрипт переходит к следующей ссылке

*Какие будут мысли? Заранее благодарю всех за внимание*.

Comment: Без selenium и аналогов — очевидно, никак, потому что скрипт будет привязан к браузерным функциям типа DOM и XMLHttpRequest. Изучайте, что этот скрипт делает и какие запросы отправляет, и переписывайте на питон

Comment: К сожалению, на `python` подобных библиотек не знаю, но для `ruby`, например, я использую gem [**mechanize**](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize). Когда-то видел аналог на `python`. А так, по сути, это тоже эмуляция браузера и парсинг ответов.

Comment: Кроме selenium есть куча других вариантов -- QWebView (Qt4, webkit), QWebEngineView (Qt5, chronium), еще я помню есть phantomjs и куча других: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers

Answer (score 0):

Порывшись в функциях, я нашёл, что список всех друзей пользователя можно найти в этой директории:

[image]

Спасибо всем за внимание.